# Node.js Spawn vs. Execute

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, spawn

In an online training video I am watching to learn Node, the narrator says that "spawn is better for longer processes involving large amounts of data, whereas execute is better for short bits of data."

Why is this? *What is the difference between the child_process spawn and execute functions in Node.js, and when do I know which one to use?*

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The main difference is that `spawn` is more suitable for long-running processes with huge output. That's because `spawn` streams input/output with a child process. On the other hand, `exec` buffers output in a small (by default **1MB**, 200 KB till v11.x) buffer. `exec` first spawns a subshell, and then tries to execute your process. To cut a long story short, use `spawn` in case you need a lot of data streamed from a child process and `exec` if you need features like shell pipes, redirects or even more than one program at a time.

Some useful links - [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-execfile-spawn-exec-and-fork-in-node) [Hacksparrow](https://www.hacksparrow.com/nodejs/difference-between-spawn-and-exec-of-node-js-child-rocess.html)

Comment: I'm also a beginner of node. I noticed that both `exec` and `spawn` return `ChildProcess` object. The doc says `spawn` streams `stdout` while `exec` buffers it, so I tried this: `cp.stdout.on("data", ...)` where the `cp` was returned by `exec`. It turned out the data was also streaming out piece by piece. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @Zhou you can use the returned ChildProcess object from `exec` similar to how you would use it from `spawn`, however, it would kinda defeat the purpose of using `exec` as that function abstracts away the need to deal with the streams. But behind the scenes those streams are still present, `exec` just deals with collecting the data from them for you. What you discovered is just that those streams are technically still available to you when using `exec`. However, there's normally no real need for them.

Answer (score 88):

- child process created by `spawn()`

  - does not spawn a shell
  - streams the data returned by the child process (data flow is constant)
  - has no data transfer size limit
- child process created by `exec()`

  - does spawn a shell in which the passed command is executed
  - buffers the data (waits till the process closes and transfers the data in on chunk)
  - maximum data transfer up to Node.js v.12.x was 200kb (by default), but since Node.js v.12x was increased to 1MB (by default)

-main.js (file)

```
var {spawn, exec} = require('child_process');

    // 'node' is an executable command (can be executed without a shell) 
    // uses streams to transfer data (spawn.stout)  
var spawn = spawn('node', ['module.js']);     
spawn.stdout.on('data', function(msg){         
    console.log(msg.toString())
});

    // the 'node module.js' runs in the spawned shell 
    // transfered data is handled in the callback function 
var exec = exec('node module.js', function(err, stdout, stderr){
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

-module.js (basically returns a message every second for 5 seconds than exits)

```
var interval;
interval = setInterval(function(){
    console.log( 'module data' );
    if(interval._idleStart > 5000) clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```

- the `spawn()` child process returns the message `module data` every 1 second for 5 seconds, because the data is 'streamed'
- the `exec()` child process returns one message only `module data module data module data module data module data` after 5 seconds (when the process is closed) this is because the data is 'buffered'

NOTE that neither the `spawn()` nor the `exec()` child processes are designed for running node modules, this demo is just for showing the difference, (if you want to run node modules as child processes use the `fork()` method instead)

Comment: As a side note, avoid doing `var spawn = spawn(...)` and `var exec = exec(...)`, as that would overwrite the functions.

Comment: ```spawn``` can run a shell, if the option.shell attribute is set accordingly. see: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options

Comment: much more clear than most upvoted

Answer (score 31):

A good place to start is the NodeJS [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

For 'spawn' the documentation state:

> The child_process.spawn() method spawns a new process using the given command, with command line arguments in args. If omitted, args defaults to an empty array.

While for 'exec':

> Spawns a shell then executes the command within that shell, buffering any generated output. The command string passed to the exec function is processed directly by the shell and special characters (vary based on shell) need to be dealt with accordingly.

The main thing appears to be whether you need handle the output of the command or not, which I imagine could be the factor impacting performance (I haven't compared). If you care only about process completion then 'exec' would be your choice. Spawn opens streams for stdout and stderr with ondata events, exec just returns a buffer with stdout and stderr as strings.

Comment: The last line of this answer should read: if you care only about process completion then 'exec' would be your choice. Spawn opens streams for stdout en stderr with ondata events, exec just returns a buffer with stdout and stderr as strings.

Comment: I argue with that "A good place to start is the NodeJS". I just started and couldn't filter out the differences, too big wall of text hit me hard. I read about one, scrolled down and forgot what I read. I know RTFM is King, but FM to get read should be more humane

Comment: Agreed with @Marecky. The nodejs docs are like a dictionary: good references for individual elements, but poorly suited at highlighting the difference between similar ones.

Answer (score 4):

A quote from the official docs:

> For convenience, the `child_process` module provides a handful of synchronous and asynchronous alternatives to `child_process.spawn()` and `child_process.spawnSync()`. Each of these alternatives are implemented on top of `child_process.spawn()` or `child_process.spawnSync()`.